# Do actions in "Mad Moxxi's Underdome Riot" affect challenges?

Tags: borderlands, borderlands-mad-moxxis-underdome

I've been playing through Borderlands again, trying to complete all the missions. Occasionally, I've unlocked challenges in the game like "Not Really a People Person" (Kill 250 Humans). Some of these challenges are quite time-consuming and since I have yet to complete "Mad Moxxi's Underdome Riot", I was wondering, **do kills and other actions in the underdome count towards challenges?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they do count. I've completed a human kills challenge in a Riot Arena. The [Borderlands Wiki article on this DLC](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Mad_Moxxi%27s_Underdome_Riot#Mechanics) has this to say (emphasis added):

> No experience is gained from kills inside the Underdome and consequently weapon proficiencies are not affected, although **it is still possible to complete challenges for experience**.

Comment: I've completed numerous challenges in the Underdome, one even leveling me up, IIRC.